# Why is it showing "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" in code snippet but not in the main code block?

Tags: python-3.x, list, int, typeerror, nested-lists

I was trying to learn **nested lists** in Python, the question was to find the person with second highest score reading 3 inputs,i.e., no. of entries, name of student and score of student.

My code is working fine when I'm executing following :

```
ns = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
   name = input()
   score = float(input())
   ns += [[name, score]]

sc = sorted(set([x[1] for x in ns]))

for name in sorted(x[0] for x in ns if x[1] == sc[1]):
   print(name)
```

But when I try to execute a snippet of that code:

```
ns = [21,21,13,24,45,6]
sc = sorted(set([x[1] for x in ns]))
print(sc)
```

it's giving me error:

```
 sc = sorted(set([x[1] for x in ns]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

**Is it because the list in the snippet is of integers?** 
**If so, how to implement this and why is it working in the first code?**

Answer (score 1):

The `x` in `[x[1] for x in ns]` is an `int` and not subscriptable.  Instead, you could write `[x for x in ns]` which throws no error.  Note that `ns` here is just a list, not a list of lists.

However, in the first piece of code that you wrote, `ns` as defined in `ns += [[name, score]]` is actually a list of list and thus you can use nested subscripts, say `ns[[1]]`.

To sort your list of `[score, name]`s, just call `sorted` on `ns` (where `ns` is a list of lists for example):

```
ns = [[21, 'tom'], [21, 'john'], [13, 'ali'], [24, 'sarah']]
ns = sorted(ns)
ns
```

which will sort the nested list based on score and name, in that order:

```
# [[13, 'ali'], [21, 'john'], [21, 'tom'], [24, 'sarah']]
```

Comment: @LogicalRetard please look at my updated answer and if you find it helpful, please accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark beside it.